# YouTube API Videocount

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to pull the count of how many videos is uploaded onto an YouTube channel, but I'm having problems. I want to show the number of videos uploaded to the channel, like this does with other statistics:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/imsparky15?alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$stats_data = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];

echo 'lastWebAccess = '.$stats_data['lastWebAccess'].'<br />';
echo 'subscriberCount = '.$stats_data['subscriberCount'].'<br />';
echo 'videoWatchCount = '.$stats_data['videoWatchCount'].'<br />';
echo 'viewCount = '.$stats_data['viewCount'].'<br />';
echo 'totalUploadViews = '.$stats_data['totalUploadViews'].'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead you can just use the Data API v3, do a [channels->list API call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list).

In the response, you will get it with [statistics.videoCount](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#statistics.videoCount)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={CHANNEL_ID}&fields=items%2Fstatistics&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[Also usernames are not unique, use channel id's everywhere.](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/youtube-google-api-and-you.html)

Comment: feel free to verify the answer, so it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>[This answer was originally edited into the question by [user2690217](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2690217/user2690217). The original question has been reinstated, and the answer moved into this Community Wiki post.]</sub>

---

This will give you a count of videos that a channel has uploaded:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME?alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$stats_data = $data['entry']['gd$feedLink'];

echo $stats_data[4]['countHint'];
?>
```

Updated with YouTube-API v3:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={CHANNEL_ID}&fields=items%2Fstatistics&key={YOUR_API_KEY}');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$stats_data = $data['items']['0']['statistics'];
echo $stats_data['videoCount'];
?>
```